# Creating a voxel chunk with a single VBO - How to translate the coordinates of each block and add it to the VBO chunk?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, voxel

I'm trying to make a opengl voxel engine similar to minecraft.

I have created a chunk class and I want to put all of the vertices for the whole chunk into a single VBO. I was previously only putting each block into a vbo and making a call to render each block.

I am a bit confused about how I can translate the coordinates of each block in the chunk when I'm putting all vertices into one vbo.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
public void drawChunk() {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
        GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
        GL11.glColorPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);


        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

public void putVertices(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
    float l_length = 1.0f;
    float l_height = 1.0f;
    float l_width = 1.0f;
    vertexPositionData.put(new float[]{
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty,zOffset +  l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,

            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty,zOffset +  -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz

    });
}

public void createChunk() {
    vertexPositionData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer((24*3)*activateBlocks);

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                if(blocks[x][y][z].getActive()) {
                    putVertices(x, y, z);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vertexPositionData.flip();

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionData,
            GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    float[] cubeColorArray = new float[(24*3)*activateBlocks];
    for(int i=0; i<(24*3)*activateBlocks; i++) {
        cubeColorArray[i] = random.nextFloat();
    }
    FloatBuffer vertexTextureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer((24*3)*activateBlocks);
    vertexTextureData.put(cubeColorArray);
    vertexTextureData.flip();

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexTextureData,
            GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glEnd();
}
```

What's any easy way to translate the vertices of each block into its correct position? I was previously using glTranslatef with each call to render block but this won't work now. 
What I am doing now also does not work, the blocks all render in stacks on top of each other and it looks like this:

EDIT: it appears that my vbo is only rendering one block and not the whole chunk.  I can't figure out why this is the case.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NyFtBTI.png]

Comment: If it is correctly adding blocks to the VBO, why have you given us that code? More helpful code would be where you call that function and when you render.

Comment: It isnt correctly adding blocks to the VBO.  It only appears to be adding one block to the VBO.  If I set my program to render only one chunk there will only appear to be one block on the screen (it should be rendering 16x16 blocks.

Comment: Then why are you showing us it working 10x10? By the looks of that also it does look like the creation of a block is correct, all the vertices look correct to me..and that's what that function does, add one block.

Comment: Sorry, positing the image was probably a mistake.  The image is of a 10x10 array of chunks.  What it should look like [is this](http://i.imgur.com/yaueQCF.png?1).  This is what it looked like before I placed all of the chunks vertices into one VBO but instead was stored a single block in the VBO and had a render call for each block. Trying to place the whole chunks vertices in a single VBO results in it [looking like this](http://i.imgur.com/9jphhnF.png) when trying to render a single 16x16 chunk to the screen.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the draw method I am using to draw the chunk.  Maybe this is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.  The problem was in my drawChunk method.

```
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
```

Was changed to:

```
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24*activateBlocks);
```